# Django-templates: share custom inclusion tag between apps

Tags: django, django-templates

There is a lot of questions about finding templates, but I can't find anything related to custom tags.

I have following schematic project structure:

`/
|- app1
|   |- templatetags
|   |    |- my_helpers.py
|   |- templates
|        |- my_helpers
|            |- my_tag.html
|- app2
    |- templates
        |- include
        |    |- inclusion.html
        |- base.html`

In `my_helpers.py` a simple inclusion tag is defined:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()    
@register.inclusion_tag('my_helpers/my_tag.html')
def my_tag(...):
    ...
```

`app2/templates/base.html` looks like this:

```
{% load my_helpers %}
... some markup ...
{% my_tag %}
{% include 'include/inclusion.html' %}
```

And here `my_tag` works just fine. But when I'm trying to use it also inside 'include/inclusion.html' (I've added a `{% load my_helpers %}` tag there), it fails with this:

```
django.template.base.TemplateDoesNotExist
TemplateDoesNotExist: my_helpers/my_tag.html
```

As I understand, it looks for templates only in current app. But why it happens only for `include`d templates? And is it possible to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can take advantage of Django template loader's feature.
You can create your project structure like below--

`|- templates
|     |- common_templates
|             |- my_tag.html
|- app1
|   |- templatetags
|   |    |- my_helpers.py
|   |- templates
|        |- my_helpers
|
|- app2
    |- templates
        |- include
        |    |- inclusion.html
        |- base.html`

and your my_helpers.py can be like

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()    
@register.inclusion_tag('common_templates/my_tag.html')
def my_tag(...):
    ...
```